# Unexpected behaviour of a shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, stdin

I have two scripts:

#### foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "one\ntwo" |
while read line; do
    cat not-existing
    echo hello $line
done
```

#### bar.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "one\ntwo" |
while read line; do
    ssh user@machine 'cat not-existing' # Here is the only difference
    echo hello $line
done
```

---

And now I run them

```
$ ./foo.sh 
cat: not-existing: No such file or directory
hello one
cat: not-existing: No such file or directory
hello two

$ ./bar.sh 
cat: not-existing: No such file or directory
hello one
```

The output of `bar.sh` is surprising to me. I would expect it to be the same for both scripts.

Why does the output of `foo.sh` and `bar.sh` differ? Is it a bug or a feature?

---

#### Note

The following works as I expect, i.e. the output of this is the same as the output of `foo.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in `echo -e "one\ntwo"`; do
    ssh user@machine 'cat not-existing'
    echo hello $line
done
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `bar.sh`, the `two` is consumed by `ssh`.  In the last example, the full output from `echo` is used by `for` before it starts looping.

To avoid having `ssh` gobble up your data from standard input, use `ssh -n`.  This will hook up the standard input of `ssh` with `/dev/null` rather than with the standard input of the `while` loop.

This will do what you expect it to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "one\ntwo" |
while read line; do
    ssh -n user@machine 'cat not-existing' # Here is the only difference
    echo hello $line
done
```

If you had written

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -e "one\ntwo" |
while read line; do
    ssh user@machine 'cat'
    echo hello $line
done
```

then the `cat` on the remote machine would have outputted `two` since its standard input is handed down to it from `ssh` which in turn got it from the loop and `echo`. It will print `two` rather than `one` since the first line of input already has been consumed by `read`.